# Is the 9th arrondissement of Paris only a tourist neighborhood?

Tags: paris

I heard from a Parisien guy that most locals avoid the centre of Paris.

I'm looking to stay in Paris for a few days, but I don't like to stay too close to attractions (just close enough to go walking for some of them), because when you stay too much close from the tourist area everything that you buy on the shops around will be more expensive, correct?

My question is: If I stay on 9th arrondissement, my experience will be strictly touristy?

Answer (score 6):

You should be careful with what people are telling you about Paris :)

From one street to another, the situation can be drastically different. So if you stay in the 9th arrondissement, you will find tourist places but you will also mostly find residential and office areas. People probably tell you that this is a big tourist place because of the retail stores around the Opera but you can stay away from these.

Answer (score 6):

Paris is expensive; Paris is full of tourists.

The 9th arrondissement, like every other arrondissement (except maybe the 1st) offer a wide assortment of dwellers, lot of families, lot of office workers.

There are schools in the area (my way of knowing if it is locals or tourists) , so you know there are families; if there are families, there are proximity stores ( food, clothing...) and restaurants and cafés.

IMO, the area between Métro Saint-Georges and Métro Poissonière is nice.

(crap, now I want to go back to Paris !!)